Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') but file has been uploaded to mongodb
I have created API to upload mp3 using multer gridfs, then test it with Postman. I got

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

error, but I have checked uploads.files and uploads.chunks on MongoDB Atlas, the file has uploaded, this is the config
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    if (file.mimetype === "audio/mp3" || file.mimetype === "audio/mpeg") {
      return {
        filename: Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname),
        bucketName: "uploads",
      };
    }
    return console.log("wrong file type:" + file.mimetype);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
router.post("/track/upload", upload.single("file"), trackController.postTrack);

This is the error here:
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
    at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emitFile (D:\nemoth\sound_seed\node_modules\multer-gridfs-storage\lib\gridfs.js:306:31)
    at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:955:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:90:21)

Node.js v22.11.0```


I think the problem occurs at upload.single('file') but file has been uploaded to MongoDB and nothing further

Please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace. Also, where exactly do you see the error?
